# Dictionary <string, uint> to comma-separated string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
// Below is an array which contains master data
string[] masterData = { "324", "233", "32", "423", "23435" };

// Below string will always contain a comma separated subset of above master data
string abc = "233,423,99";
```

What I need is to have a dictionary having string key of all masterData array values & have the value set to 1 only for those keys which are in the string abc. All other keys need value of 0. In this case, dictionary should be of type string & value should be of type uint. In this case, dictionary should be as shown below:

```
String   uint
 "324"   0
 "233"   1
 "32"    0
 "423"   1
 "23435" 0
```

Note that 99 from string is ignored as only all master data should be present in dictionary.

Is there a way to do it using linq? If not, what other shorted way is it possible with?

Also, how do I perform the above operation in the reverse way using linq or any other shorted approach i.e. convert `dictionary<string, uint>` back to comma separated string? And this string should contain only those keys from the dictionary whose value is 1.

Note: dictionary value can be either 1 or 0 only.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify what concrete problem you hitting while trying to write the code (short of "plz give me teh codez"). Some example of what you tried would make question much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var abcArray = abc.Split(',');
masterData.ToDictionary(p => p, p => (uint)(abcArray.Contains(p) ? 1 : 0));
```

Comment: how abt the reverse operation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Concat` to add together the first array and the split string, then use `GroupBy` to group the same numbers, then just create the `Dictionary` from that, the duplicated items will have a `Count` greater than 1.

```
 var dict = masterData
            .Concat(abc.Split(','))
            .GroupBy(x => x)
            .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Count() > 1 ? 1 : 0);
```

To reverse, select all the strings where the `Value` is 1 and `Join` the sting

```
string result = string.Join(",", dict.Where(x => x.Value > 0)
                                     .Select(k => k.Key)
                                     .ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

`string abc = "233,423,99";
var subset = abc.Split(',');
var result = masterData.ToDictionary(k => k, k => Convert.ToUInt32(subset.Contains(k)));
var reversedResult = result.Where(p => p.Value == 1).Select(p => p.Key).ToArray();`

https://dotnetfiddle.net/5eU5B0